# linking glbinding with cmake

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, linker, glbinding

I'm trying to use glbinding in my own project. I'm using cmake to build everything. The problem is linker cannot find this library. Probably I don't build library thus it cannot be linked, but I don't know how to achive that.
I've written linking code according to https://github.com/hpicgs/glbinding#linking-binaries.

Cmake:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(AKOpenGLEngine ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} glbinding )
find_package(glbinding REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLBINDING_INCLUDES})
target_link_libraries(AKOpenGLEngine glbinding ${GLBINDING_LIBRARIES})
```

Error:

```
Linking CXX executable AKOpenGLEngine
ld: library not found for -lglbinding
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <glbinding/gl/gl.h>

int main(void) {
    glbinding::Binding::initialize();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

My current project structure:

[image: project structure]

Comment: So your question is what again? "how do I build 'libglbinding' ?". I would assume just do the usual cmake and then make.

Comment: I've added glbinding as git submodule. I want to build my project with glbinding with one cmake, not build glbinding separately

Comment: then you may need to add one cmakelists that first does `add_subdirectory( glbinding )` (or whatever you called your directory)

Comment: I've tried adding add_subdirectory in main CMakeLists. I get several errors that it cannot find README.md or LICENSE

Comment: Why not add it with `ExternalProject_Add`? [Git submodules are evil](http://slopjong.de/2013/06/04/git-why-submodules-are-evil/)

Comment: You need to use only `${GLBINDING_LIBRARIES}` in `target_link_libraries` and remove `glbinding`.`target_link_libraries(AKOpenGLEngine ${GLBINDING_LIBRARIES})`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to remove the `glbinding` from `target_link_libraries`? `${GLBINDING_LIBRARIES}` should be sufficient; it passes `<your_specific_file_path_to_glbinding_library>` to the linker. With `-lglbinding` the linker searches for a library within some default directories, your glbinding or build directory not included, thus throwing a `library not found`. To verify the content of `${GLBINDING_LIBRARIES}` you can print it to cmake output, e.g., via `message(STATUS ${GLBINDING_LIBRARIES})`. However, i also suggest to integrate glbinding as external project as suggested by @janisz.

EDIT: sorry, didn't see the valid, but collapsed answer of @jet47